SMD transistor identification
What is value of "HF" as written on an SMD transistor?
I think it should be BJT or FET.
It is very small and has 3 terminals.
Please I honestly need to replace it.

Welcome! Please provide a photo of it and exact capsule dimensions.

Likely, Transistor is C1815. you can search c1815 smd in google.

Consider editing the answer to include a link to a datasheet which backs this up. The Rectron C1815 datasheet is for a NPN transistor in a SOT-23 package which has a device marking of HF.
